# XNA using WinForms: Building Content?

Tags: winforms, xna, directory, output

I am currently trying to use XNA in WinForms and have some troubles with building/loading content.

Using the [Microsoft sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) on how to use XNA in a WinForm, I have already implemented a user control which runs fine for now.
I then tried to setup the ContentManager using a new "Empty Content Project" and "Windows Game Library" like the sample.

However, after adding a SpriteFont to the Content Project(Root Directory = "Content") and trying to load it, I am getting the error that it could not find the file. I looked into the Debug folder and could not find the Content folder which should contain the compiled SpriteFont, though I found it in the Content folder of the ContentLibrary.

My question now is, how would I setup my project to always build the content in the Debug/Release folder? I could not find anything related to this in the sample yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't added a content reference from your Windows XNA project to your content project. It's on the right click menu where you would add a normal style reference.